# iOS cannot receive push notifications through FCM (can through APNs)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift5

I was about to ask this question on stackoverflow, but I just figured it out. I'm posting this anyway for posterity's sake, as this bug cost me days and I could not find any mentions of it on this site.

I could not send push notifications through FCM after making two different schemes and selecting a different plist depending on the scheme in AppDelegate. The code to select my plist looked like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    // NOTE: DONT call registrationDataManager here or any other VC that uses Firebase before it's configured
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    let window: UIWindow? = nil

//XXX OVERRIDE INIT BREAKS SWIZZLING -- DO NOT USE
    override init() {
        super.init()
        let buildFor = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["BUILD_FOR"]! as String
        var firebasePlistFileName = "GoogleService-Info"

        if buildFor == "PROD" {
            //firebasePlistFileName = "GoogleService-Info-Production"
            firebasePlistFileName = "RELEASE-NEW-GoogleService-Info"
            print("--- USING PRODUCTION / RELEASE PLIST")
        }
        else {
            firebasePlistFileName = "DEBUG-NEW-GoogleService-Info"
            print("--- USING DEBUG PLIST")
        }

        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: firebasePlistFileName, ofType: "plist")
        guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath!) else {
                assert(false, "Couldn't load config file")
                return
        }

        FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
//       FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

If you try to do the above, you may notice an error that looks something like

```
[AppDelegateSwizzler] App Delegate does not conform to UIApplicationDelegate protocol firebase
```

Answer (score 0):

WHAT YOU SHOULD DO INSTEAD:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        let buildFor = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["BUILD_FOR"]! as String
        var firebasePlistFileName = "GoogleService-Info"

        if buildFor == "PROD" {
            //firebasePlistFileName = "GoogleService-Info-Production"
            firebasePlistFileName = "RELEASE-NEW-GoogleService-Info"
            print("--- USING PRODUCTION / RELEASE PLIST")
        }
        else {
            firebasePlistFileName = "DEBUG-NEW-GoogleService-Info"
            print("--- USING DEBUG PLIST")
        }

        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: firebasePlistFileName, ofType: "plist")
        guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath!) else {
                assert(false, "Couldn't load config file")
        }

        FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)

        }
//....
```

This is assuming that you have gone to the schemes, edited schemes to have the environment variable BUILD_FOR and that it is set to PROD for your production / release scheme and then will point to the correct GoogleServices-Info plist filename based on that. This is one way to implement multiple plists with Firebase without screwing up everything.

Main point -- don't use override init unless you want to fix swizzling yourself or you know more about what you're doing than I do.